# how do you put a click counter on a last child node to count how many times you click on the last node

Tags: javascript, nodes

im makeing a face matching game and wanted to make a way of counting how many times you picked right in the alerty message would I put the counting code info in the game over function or would i make a new function to put it in the last child of the left side only?

```
<body onload='generateFaces()'>
  <h1>'Matching Game'</h1>
  <p>'Click on the extra face on the left.'<p>
  <div id='leftSide'></div>
  <div id='rightSide'></div>
  <script>
      let numberOfFaces = 5;
      const theLeftSide= document.getElementById('leftSide');
      const theRightSide= document.getElementById('rightSide');
  

      function generateFaces(){
          for (let i=0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
            const face= document.createElement('img');
            face.src= 'image/smile.png';
            const randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*400) +1;
            const randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*400) +1;
            face.style.top = randomTop + 'px';
            face.style.left = randomLeft + 'px';
            theLeftSide.appendChild(face);
          }

          const leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
          leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
          theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
          theLeftSide.lastChild.addEventListener('click', nextLevel);
          document.body.addEventListener('click', gameOver);
      }

      function nextLevel() {
          event.stopPropagation();
          numberOfFaces += 5;
          while (theLeftSide.lastChild) {
              theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.lastChild);
          }
          while (theRightSide.lastChild){
              theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.lastChild);
          }
          generateFaces();
      }

      function gameOver() {
          alert('GaMe OvEr! !\n Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum.');
          document.body.removeEventListener('click', gameOver);
          theLeftSide.lastChild.removeEventListener('click', nextLevel);
      }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to declare a variable to store how many times a user has clicked on the last node. For e.g. `let num = 0;` And then small addition in your `nextLevel()` function i.e. `num = num + 1;`. To display it on the screen, you have to declare separate HTML tag. Then you can go with `document.getElementById('clicked').innerText = num + ' times user has clicked';`. It will work properly.